# Prevent Observable from Running Again Until Complete

Tags: angular, observable

In an Angular4/Ionic3 environment using observables. Slider with slides on a page. When a person swipes to move to the next slide, a multi-step, long-running observable is fired. Currently, when a person swipes again the second observable instance runs (before the first instance has finished).

How do I make the second observable wait for the first observable to complete? I don't want to block the person from being able to swipe. The swipe event should simply queue up the next observable.

**Current Timeline**

1. Swipe1
2. Observable Instance1 = start
3. Swipe2
4. Observable Instance2 = start
5. Observable Instance1 = end
6. Observable Instance2 = end

**Desired Timeline**

1. Swipe1
2. Observable Instance1 = start
3. Observable Instance1 = end
4. Swipe2
5. Observable Instance2 = start
6. Observable Instance2 = end

**Current Observable Pseudo Code**

```
private slideNextStart(event) {

    // Don't let this Observable be called again until it finishes.
    Observable.of(null)
    .flatMap(() => {
        console.log('start');
        // Do something.
    })
    .flatMap(() => {
        // Do something else.
    })
    .flatMap(() => {
        // Do another something else.
    })
    .subscribe(() => { console.log('end'); });
```

**Angular2 Translated Code from Julia's Answer**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

let subject = new Subject();
subject.asObservable()
    .concatMap((x: Observable<any>) => { return x })
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x));

// request 1
subject.next(Observable
    .timer(4000)
    .map(() => { console.log('req1') })
    .mapTo('req1'));

// request 2
subject.next(Observable.of('req2'));
```

Comment: You do not want to block a person from second swipe, but does the second swap result in different effect than the first one? It seems that you want to make the observables synchronized, which is not something they are made for. What happens should happen if person swipe third, forth, fifth time? Not sure about the case, but maybe some loading menu would be better option (it would cover the screen until the first swipe observable finishes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observable.concatMap is designed for this. *"Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable, in a serialized fashion waiting for each one to complete before merging the next."* [concatMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap)

```
// subject to emit observables
let subject = new Rx.Subject();

// do concatMap to sequence the requests
subject.asObservable()
 .concatMap(x=>x)
 .subscribe(x=>console.log(x))

// request 1
subject.next(Rx.Observable
    .timer(4000)
    .mapTo('req1'));

// request 2
subject.next(Rx.Observable.of('req2'));
```

Comment: Perfect! However, I haven't been able to get this to work properly in an Angular2 environment. The requests are being output to console, but the requests themselves are not running. My console.log('req1') does not output. Console logs two items (1) Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapToOperator} (2) ScalarObservable {_isScalar: true, value: "req2", scheduler: null}.

Comment: My Angular2/TypeScript code was wrong. Have updated question to correct code.